# "npm start" error with webpack-dev-server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack-dev-server

I know this is a terrible way of forming a question, but I've been working on this for several hours and have made no progress. Everything worked perfectly last night, this morning I had an update from the App Store that made me restart, now my npm server (I'm trying to learn React.js) isn't working. Here is my error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@4.0.5
3 info using node@v4.6.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle react-essential@1.0.0~prestart: react-essential@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle react-essential@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle react-essential@1.0.0~start: react-essential@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle react-essential@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle react-essential@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/FrankHarvey/Dropbox/react-practice/node_modules/.bin:/Users/FrankHarvey/anaconda2/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
10 verbose lifecycle react-essential@1.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/FrankHarvey/Dropbox/react-practice
11 silly lifecycle react-essential@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack-dev-server' ]
12 silly lifecycle react-essential@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle react-essential@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: react-essential@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
15 verbose pkgid react-essential@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /Users/FrankHarvey/Dropbox/react-practice
17 error Darwin 16.3.0
18 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
19 error node v4.6.1
20 error npm  v4.0.5
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error react-essential@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the react-essential@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the react-essential package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     webpack-dev-server
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs react-essential
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls react-essential
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I've tried:

- Switching ports
- Reverting git commits
- reinstalling node running with `sudo`

None have worked.

Comment: Try running `npm install`. Looks like the module isn't installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always good to do

```sh
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

---

Delete `webpack-dev-server` out of the `node_modules` directory and run `npm install webpack-dev-server`

Thanks to a comment, I was able to solve. I tried reinstalling by using `npm install`. This did not work. I then tried using `npm install webpack-dev-server` and got an error. It kept saying things like `xyz/abc/node_modules/xyz/node_modules/abc/.bin/file` exists. Move and try again. I tried that a few times, finally deleted the entire `webpack-dev-server` directory out of my `node_modules` directory and reinstalled. It all works now.

By the way, I used this as I was using Lynda.com's "React.js Essential Training". Only including this info for other's who might have this issue.

Comment: It didn't work for me. any other way to solve this issue? I am using Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I've deleted the whole folder node_modules and package-lock.json as well, than run npm install. After this server has started succesfully

Comment: Thanks! It worked in my case. I was getting the same error but I deleted it then installed again.

Comment: delete node_module it's best solution to all problems

Answer (score 1):

you can set this option to false in the `webpack-dev-server` config:

`quiet: true` => `quiet: false`

Answer (score 1):

Delete not only `webpack-dev-server` out of the `node_modules` directory, but also `webpack-dev-middleware`. Then run `npm install webpack-dev-middleware` and `npm install webpack-dev-server`.

Answer (score 0):

set the webpack webpack cli webpack-dev-server as per needed after that remove package-lock.json file and node module folder from the project and open your project directory in cmd and run npm install